# Android PN532 not working anymore

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am working on a project, and I'm trying to send/receive data through a PN532 connected to an Arduino Uno and an Android smartphone.
I'm using an HTC One M8 and Seeed-Studio library https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532.

The problem is that P2P mode was working, but since I've upgraded my phone from Android 4.4 (KitKat) to Android 5.0 (Lollipop) it didn't work any more. I've tried to switch to I²C and UART, but it didn't work.

When I'm using the "p2p_with_ndef_library" example, the PN532 seems to detect my phone but it prints "Failed.".

---

Update: Finally I've tried with another NFC module, and it works. My module was broken for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this by Samsung Galaxy S III and Xperia L, and it was done prefect. It should done by SPI mode only. And your data should be less than 128 byte or 139 byte. But it's better that less than 128 bytes.